# Worklight iOS push handler function when app is closed

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight iOS Push notification not handling push received function when app is closed or not running. How to trigger push handler function when push receiving in worklight?

We are using Worklight V6.0.0.0.

We testes push notification sample project in 3 different scenarios.

1. When application is in foreground we are display notification as popup(or alert). Its working fine.
2. When application is in background(active) we are display badge in status bar. While clicking on badge(calls handler function) we are redirecting app to new page. This too working correctly.
3. But when application is closed we are receiving badge, while clicking on badge the application launching directly without invoking push handler function.

Comment: What is your Worklight version? Did you test with the push notifications sample project? does it fail as well?

Comment: @IdanAdar We are using Worklight V6.0. We testes push notification sample project in 3 different senarios.

Comment: Which version of Worklight 6? 6.0.0? 6.0.0.1? 6.0.0.2? Edit your question with this information as well as the scenarios you have tested.

Comment: @IdanAdar We are using Worklight V6.0.0. We testes push notification sample project in 3 different senarios. 1.When application is in foreground we are display notification as popup(or alert).Its working fine. 2.When application is in background(active) we are display badge in status bar.While clicking on badge(calls handler function) we are redirecting app to new page.This too working correctly. 3.But when application is closed we are receiving badge,while clicking on badge the application launching directly without invoking push handler function.How can we trigger is push received or not.

Answer (score 0):

*update May 26th:*
I have tested with [the supplied test project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1xsv803inwmdpz/PushNotificationsProject.zip) and the 3rd scenario mentioned in the question worked as well:

> ..
>   ..
>
> But when application is closed we are receiving badge, while
>   clicking on badge the application launching directly without invoking
>   push handler function.

In your test project, after closing the application you are no longer in the session with the server; this means you will need to re-login.

1. Login
2. Subscribe
3. Quit app
4. Send notification to subscribed username (used during Login in step 1)
5. Tap on notification
6. App launches > Login
7. **Only now will the notification be displayed**

Scenario 3 works OK for me.

---

Try again with the latest version of Worklight 6.0.0, which is Worklight 6.0.0.2, where many push-related fixes were done and I believe also a fix for the scenario you are describing.

Worklight 6.0.0.2 developer edition [can be downloaded from here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.2.zip).
If you are an IBM customer or business partner, you can download the consumer or enterprise edition from IBM Fix Central.

Comment: I have installed fix pack 6.0.0.2 . But getting the same.

Comment: Strange. This requires debugging then, please provide a demo Worklight project that shows the same issue. Export it from Eclipse (the **Worklight** project) and upload to Dropobx.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3tzt5nhvtp9ygi/WL6.0.0.2.jpg Just tell is that correct version of Worklight 6.0.0.2

Comment: No... did you try installing the plug-in I linked to? its date is 6.0.0.201405191154

Comment: I have attached sample project in drop box link. I not invoking push received function when push notification arrives. Its invoking when we click on badge in status bar/Notification in iOS. but android its working fine. I just want to invoke push notification function whenever push arrives to mobile.

Comment: is it possible to store a variable in window.localstorage when ever the device(ios only) received notification. No matter is the app is closed or running in background.

Comment: If the app is Closed, how do you want to store something in localstorage? IMO, no.

Comment: In Android when ever notification arrives push handler function invoked directly(No matter is the app is closed or running in background). But it is not happening for ios. How can I conform that is the app is launched by clicking app icon or by clicking notification badge.

Comment: What do you mean? The app opened? then it launched. Please write in proper English; I don't understand you. The application cannot be invoked automatically, you must tap either the notification or the app icon in order to open the app, there is no other way. Android is Android and iOS is iOS.